# How to connect two Iphone/ipod/ipads for gameplay over local wifi network?

Tags: iphone, networking, multiplayer

I would like to add the option to play against another person over my wifi network in my pong game. How do I make this happen?

Also, I would like to know how to be able to have 4 players at the same time like I would if I make a monopoly type game or something similar.

I'm a newbee so please point me in the right direction or show me some code I can use for this and study.
Thanks guys
David

Answer (score 2):

The two main options seem to be GameKit (built on top of Bonjour) and Bonjour. If you're taking the GameKit route, use peer session mode for two players and server/client session mode for more than two. If you're taking the Bonjour route, good luck.

Also, Gamekit supports wi-fi and bluetooth.

> Peer-to-peer connectivity allows your game to create an ad-hoc
>   Bluetooth or local wireless network between multiple iOS-based
>   devices.

Helpful Links:
[GameKit Programming Guide: Peer-to-Peer Connectivity](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1)
[GameKit Examples at the iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=GameKit) - Try the GKTank and GKRocket examples.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Gamekit sdk.  It is an Apple sdk for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can I find working code for this anywhere? I'm a newbee so I want to find code that works and play around with. Anyone have code to share with me, it's only for learning purpose so I get a head start for school.
Thanks guys
David

Comment: I thought GameKit was a bluetooth library? Please enlighten me if i'm wrong :)